# Obtain the pandas dataframe column names in a list when one cell value equals to a specific string

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with around 20-30 columns. I would like to obtain the column names in a list when one cell value equals to the string "Fail".

The dataframe would look like this:

```
    Column_1 Column_2 ... Column_30
0      Pass   Pass          Fail
1      Pass   Pass          Pass
2      Fail   Pass          Pass
3      Pass   Pass          Pass
4      Pass   Pass          Pass
..
```

The expected result looks like such `[Column_1, Column 30]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should do the trick

```
df.columns[(df=='Fail').any(axis=0)]
```

This gives you the columns names for each column that contains at least one 'Fail' in its rows as a pandas.Index. If it must be a list, just add `.tolist()` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a list comprehension that incorporates a value check:

```
[col for col in df.columns if 'Fail' in df[col].values]
```